# Convert integer to hours and minutes - getting PL/SQL numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

I am getting

> ORA-06502 PL/SQL numeric or value error

when I am trying to execute this statement from Report Builder 6i and Oracle database 11g.

```
select to_char(to_date(lateby, 'sssss'), 'mi:ss') 
from attendancelogs   
where emp_no = :emp_no 
  and attendancedate = :dat;

late    number(15);
```

The same statement when run under SQL*Plus is running fine without any error and fetching values the way I want.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards, 
Mac

Comment: Huh, what a strange data you keep in that column; date value stored in a NUMBER datatype column, all in 'sssss' format. I've never seen anything like that. Anyway: what does that SELECT statement return when you run it in SQL*Plus? Could you post relevant sample data from the ATTENDANCELOGS table? Where do you execute that query in Reports Builder? As a "main" report's query? Or is it a formula column or something like that? If so, is the variable you used properly set (its datatype should be VARCHAR2(5), at least)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I am running it as a formula column in report builder the variable (lateby) is a numeric data type in the table this contains a integer which represents how many minutes late a employee is..

Comment: I am running it as a formula column in report builder the variable (lateby) is a numeric data type in the table this contains a integer which represents how many minutes late a employee is..  Below is the output from sql plus.

Comment: select lateby, to_char(to_date(lateby, 'sssss'), 'mi:ss') from attendancelogs where emp_no = 52                                          LATEBY TO_CH                                                                                     
         00:00                                                                                     
        0 00:00                                                                                     
      533 08:53                                                                                     
      532 08:52

Comment: any help pls...

Comment: Please, edit your initial message and post SELECT (and its result) in the question; it is unreadable if you post it as a comment. Though, it seems like LATEBY column has values like 00:00 or 08:53 - if that's so, it certainly isn't a numeric datatype but character. Help us help you; post table description, its contents (several rows), the **whole** formula column code. If you keep posting fragments and scatter them throughout comments here and in answer(s) below, it is difficult to understand what you really have and what you'd want to get.

Comment: Maybe try `lateby * INTERVAL '1' SECOND` and format the result afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a Reports bug, I don't know, but as a workaround you could try wrapping this into a stored procedure in the database as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sssss_to_miss ( p1 in varchar2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
   RETURN ( to_char(to_date(p1, 'sssss'), 'mi:ss') );
END;
/
```

Then in the Reports Code:

```
select sssss_to_miss (lateby) 
from attendancelogs   
where emp_no = :emp_no 
  and attendancedate = :dat;

late    number(15);
```

Alternatively, something like (not tested):

```
select to_char(to_number(lateby)/60,'00') || ':' || to_char(mod(to_number(lateby),60),'00') 
    from attendancelogs   
    where emp_no = :emp_no 
      and attendancedate = :dat;
```

Comment: Could you check the value of `lateby` being processed - to check there isn't a rogue value that is not `'SSSSS'` format.

Comment: I checked it, the value of lateby is a 3 digit integer only..it is a number column and does not contain a null also. It contains 0 - 999 values only

Comment: any suggestion pls..much appreciated

Comment: Did you try the server FUNCTION approach?
What is the purpose of the `late` variable declaration in your code?
Could you try padding out the `lateby` value to leading `0` so that it has a total length of 5 ( to match with `SSSSS`) ?

Comment: No i have'nt tried creating a stored procedure as yet...but I will try to do it..the purpose of late variable is it has an integer which tells how many minutes is an employee late. I want to convert this integer into hours:minutes:seconds to display in report instead of just a integer value..

Comment: I tried to create a function from toad it gives me 'IN' is not an integer value when i tried to compile..

Comment: So, change the IN type from VARCHAR2 to NUMBER .

Comment: I created the function but it is giving the same error when I run the report from report builder...don't understand where the fix is..do you suggest anything else I try...thanks in adv.

Comment: can you suggest any other way that I can convert an integer to hours:minutes:seconds please? Appreciate your help

Comment: can u let me know how i can check the log files for this error..will there be any record for this error available in the log file..thanks

Comment: Get the value of `:emp_no` and `:dat` used in the Report query. Then use those values in the same query in SQLPLUS but also print the value of `lateby` so we can see what the input value is. We need to exactly what value is being passed in. In fact, post the results of `SELECT lateby, dump(lateby) FROM attendancelogs where emp_no = XXXX attendancedate = YYYYY`.

Comment: i changed the datatype of this variable lateby which was defined as number to varchar2 in the report and removed the total for this column..it is working now..but i need to know how i can make total for this column now...thanks for your support